# How to create a non-friend global function with pointer to object?

Tags: c++

I got stuck with creating a non-friend global function that has one parameter with pointer.
In simple words I need a function that get passesd object via pointer, and write out all its members.
So far I created a public declaration in MyClass

```
   void WriteOutMyClass2 (MyClass *kp2);
```

And I created the function as well

```
void WriteOutMyClass2 (MyClass *kp2)
{

    cout << "_a :" <<kp2._a <<endl;

}
```

but unfortunately I'm getting an error:

**request for member ‘_a’ in ‘kp2’, which is of pointer type ‘MyClass*’ (maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?)**

I've pasted code at rexter.com, so you can look at that here.
http://rextester.com/URTI56137

And additionally I'm attaching the whole code here.

```
class MyClass
{
   private:
   int _a;
   int* c;
   int size;
   static int counter;

   public:
   friend void WriteOutMyClass1 (MyClass &kp1);
   void WriteOutMyClass2 (MyClass *kp2);
   MyClass() //default constructor
   {
       _a=0;
       size = 10;
       c = new int [size];
       for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
       {
           c[i] = 1;
       }
       counter++;
   }



};


//Initialize friend fucntion
void WriteOutMyClass1 (MyClass &kp1)
{

    cout << "_a :" <<kp1._a <<endl;
    cout << "size :" <<kp1.size<<endl;
    cout << "counter :" <<kp1.counter<<endl;
        for(int i = 0; i<kp1.size; i++)
       {
            cout << "c[" << i << "] = "  << kp1.c[i] << endl;
       }
}

//Initialize non-friend global fucntion.
void WriteOutMyClass2 (MyClass *kp2)
{

    cout << "_a :" <<kp2._a <<endl; // here I'm getting error.

}
int main()
{


}
```

edit:

What excatly I'm trying to do is, get access to private members of MyClass from non-firend function declared outside MyClass. 
Function shouldn't be static, and access to private members is needed via getter or not. I'm not aware of c++ possibilties.
I appreciate any help!

ps: the "->" isn't enough, because the "_a" field is private.
How would it looks with a getter?

edit2:

I unduerstand that some rules were broken but this code is an exercise I got from an university. It's specially done to show some approch.
Unfortunatelly variable names are as they are, of course I could rename them but I forgot.

Comment: Maybe you meant to use ‘->’ ?

Comment: The message is self-explanatory.   Instead of `kp2._a` in the function, use `kp2->_a`.    That's how access of struct members via a pointer works.

Comment: Those members are private, that would be an obstacle if you do not provide getters.

Comment: @Yunnosch - the function is a member, so has access to private members.

Comment: Op asks explicitly about non-friend function. So I assume that the `friend` used in the code quote is meant to go away with the answer to this question.

Comment: Please elaborate what you mean by "non-friend global function". I would guess a function which is not a member of the class and not a friend either. But reading comments and answers, it seems not entirely clear to other readers. Do you know the meaning of a static member function/method? Would that be enough for your purpose? Are you aware of the meaning of the `private` in your class declaration? Is providing public "getters" an option? Those are members which allow to read (but e.g. not write) private member values.

Comment: I know the meaning of the static keyword. What excatly I'm trying to do is, get access to private members of MyClass from non-firend function declared outside MyClass. 
Function shouldn't be static, and access to private members is needed via getter or not. I'm not aware of c++ possibilties.

Comment: Please edit your question to put that very helpful explanation directly in there.

Comment: ok, i will edit post within 15 min max

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The diagnostic is quite clear and even gives a suggestion.

You need

```
  cout << "_a :" <<kp2->_a <<endl;
  //                  ^^
```

with a `->`  not a `.` in the body of `WriteOutMyClass2`

BTW, you might add `assert(kp2 != nullptr);` before that. If `kp2` happens to be null or invalid, you have [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (and probably a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)) and that is [scary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108).

You could declare your `WriteOutMyClass2` as a `static` function (I'm not sure you want that, your intentions are unclear).

BTW, don't be afraid of `friend` functions, even if having too much of them is bad smell. You might want to (and in your case, you probably should) define many [getters and setters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method).

I recommend spending several days reading more about C++ (at least [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11)) since it is a very difficult programming language. So read a good [C++ programming](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/) book and look into some [C++ reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) site.

Don't forget to enable all warnings and debug information, so compile on the command line with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Learn how to use the debugger (e.g.  [`gdb`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)).

Be aware of the (empirical) [rule of five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) (which your code breaks, and that is a mistake). Prefer standard [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer). Perhaps you might remove `size` and declare `std::vector<int> _c;` instead of having `c` (and `size`) as private members.

Later on, consider defining your own [`operator <<` for output](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) of your types.

Study for inspiration the source code of several [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) projects (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/)) coded in C++.

> What exactly I'm trying to do is, get access to private members of MyClass

Wrong approach. You should define getter functions, and they generally are `public:` (even if some of them could be `private:` or `protected:`).

> the "->" isn't enough, because the "_a" field is private. How would it looks with a getter?

Your current code is in very bad shape. But you might add a getter member function:

```
// inside class MyClass
public:
   int getA(void) const {return _a;};
```

and then use `kp2->getA()` instead of `kp2->_a`

BTW, you should consider more readable names (probably longer ones) for your public interface. If your member field `_a` is meant to be some price, its getter function should better be named `getPrice` (or perhaps just `Price`) than `getA` ...

It is important to keep your code readable (even to yourself, in a few months). Code is more often read than written (or compiled). Developer's time costs much more than computer time.

Comment: Will that work with private members, once OP changes, as indicated by the title, to non-friend?

Comment: what exactly is the diferrence between . and -> ?
i came from c# and some aspects are totally confusing? 
Obviously i tried the "->" operator but with no result.

Comment: `a->b` == `(*a).b`

Comment: I unduerstand that some rules were broken but this code is an exercise I got from an university. It's specially done to show some approch.